# How do I get rid of a fatal error on wordpress website with elementor?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

How do I get rid of this error?

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\Scheme_Typography' not found in /home4/mtsclass/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rselements/widgets/testimonial-slider/testimonail-slider-widget.php:628 Stack trace: #0 /home4/mtsclass/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(2280): Rsaddon_Pro_Testimonial_Slider_Widget->_register_controls() #1 /home4/mtsclass/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(494): Elementor\Controls_Stack->init_controls() #2 /home4/mtsclass/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/widget-base.php(177): Elementor\Controls_Stack->get_stack() #3 /home4/mtsclass/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(300): Elementor\Widget_Base->get_stack() #4 /home4/mtsclass/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(2369): Elementor\Controls_Stack->get_controls() #5 /home4/mtsclass/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php(1105): Elementor\Control in /home4/mtsclass/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rselements/widgets/testimonial-slider/testimonail-slider-widget.php on line 628

Comment: The fix is to make sure that class is included in the script. Can't help much more because we don't know how it's supposed to be included, what files it's supposed to be in, or anything else.

Answer (score 2):

This is a removed function in Elementor 3.6.0+.

Roll back Elementor to 3.5.6 if you need to get your site up again quickly.

To solve the actual issue for the longer term, check which plugin tries to use the removed function and remove/deactivate/fix it.